# Ember save data to store and display without having a server api

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a users model which fetches data from github users api (`https://api.github.com/users`). While displaying the list there is a add button which should add the user to a shortlist section below and which has a remove button to remove user from shortlist. I don't have api to save shortlist data. What  is the best approach to make this work?

**Try 1:** Created a shortlist model and used store.push

```
this.store.push({
    data: [{
        id: user.id,
        type: 'shortlist',
        attributes: {
        login: userData.login,
        avatar_url: userData.avatar_url,
        type: userData.type
        }
    }]
});
```

and used `item.unloadRecord();` to remove from model. But did nor found a way to fetch all record and show as `this.store.peakAll('shortlist')` wasen't working.

**Try 2:** Used localstorage to add user to shortlist, display and remove but here it needs page reload to display the add/remove changes as i used `setupController` to get the items from localstorage.

Please suggest how to do this in best possible way.

Comment: Are you using Ember Data? Do you want to persist the data in users browser or is this state only needed for running instance? Should it be synchronized between different tabs? There are a lot of details missing.

Comment: Yes i want user data to persist as when switch between routes, data should show. And for this requirement i am not sure how can use ember data as i don't have backend api to save this shortlist.

Comment: Both approaches should work, although I do recommend the second. Please post the code from your model definition as well as your route so we can see what might be going wrong.

Comment: plz check here - https://github.com/sajaldas/gitusers/blob/master/app/routes/users.js

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Persist variables between page loads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/persist-variables-between-page-loads)

Comment: You could also use https://www.ember-cli-mirage.com/ in production

Comment: there is also this: https://github.com/genkgo/ember-localforage-adapter/